Proof of equivalence between two induction rules for system T of Gödel
I want to prove a claim that I found in Combinators, lambda-terms and proof theory by Stenlund (p.119). More specifically, there are two induction rules for system T (I use a bit different notation and definitions. If I forget to explain something please ask me) for $M,N$ terms of type $int$
$$(IR) \qquad M[x:=0]=t, M[x:=s(v)]=N[y:=M[x:=v],x:=v]\vdash M[x:=w]=R_{int}t(\lambda y^{int}.\lambda x^{int}.N)w$$
and
$$(IR') \qquad M[x:=0]=N[x:=0], M[x:=v]=N[x:=v]\rightarrow M[x:=s(v)]=N[x:=s(v)]\vdash M[x:=w]=N[x:=w]$$
And I want to prove that they are equivalent. So please tell me if I proceed in a correct way.
IR $\rightarrow$ IR'
Suppose that I have a prime formula $M=N$ in T ($M,N\in int$ and $x$ may occur free in both or in one of them) which I can prove with IR. Suppose also that the assumptions of IR' are provable in T (which of the two rules can I use for them? IR' because I need an inductive hypothesis?). I must prove the conclusion of IR'
Do I have to use induction on the formation of M and N?
IR' $\rightarrow$ IR In a similar way

I reference Goodstein Recursive number theory 1957 p.104-105 and I will add a proof in the future.
